# Adding language to MiKTeX installation

Tags: miktex, languages, babel

My native language is Serbian and it is included in MiKTeX distribution for Windows. However, there is only latin version of it, and I'd like to use cyrillic Serbian. I tried searching the Internet about the issue and found [this](http://lists.debian.org/debian-tetex-maint/2002/05/msg00048.html) post.

These files are based on Russian language, and after inspecting them, I found that the translations are just fine. I copied the contents of the files to two files (serbianc.ldf and serbianc.sty) and placed these files in tex\generic\babel folder where other language files reside.

Next, I added the following line to babel.sty (among other language definitions):

```
\DeclareOption{serbianc}{\input{serbianc.ldf}}
```

When trying to use the language in TeX document, LaTeX fails at the following line:

```
\usepackage[serbianc]{babel}
```

with the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `serbianc.ldf' not found.
```

I have also tried going to MiKTeX settings and refreshing file name database to no avail.

I'm rather new to TeX - it might be a big shot for me, but I do have a lot of programming skills and am eager to learn about it. The resources I found on the Internet are rather scarce and mainly Unix related.

What am I missing here? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you run `texhash` (or whatever the MikTeX equivalent is)?

Comment: I guess this is equivalent to refreshing FNDB through GUI in MiKTeX. I did run it, nonetheless. Here's the output:
Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\Witchunter\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Creating fndb for user root directory (C:\Users\Witchunter\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Skipping common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
Skipping common root directory ("V:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9")...

Comment: Don't put local files in the main root (programdata\miktex ...), use a local root instead (see manual of miktex). But if you use the main root then you must update the FNDB in admin mode.

Comment: Thank you both, Ulrike's suggestion did the trick. Ulrike, feel free to post the answer, I'll accept it as the best.

Comment: @Ulrike: Can your please post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here as wanted the comment as answer:

Don't put local files in the main root (programdata\miktex ...), use a local root instead (see manual of miktex). But if you use the main root then you must update the FNDB in admin mode.

Comment: See now also  [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).