# Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX

Tags: installing, miktex, texmf, folders

In TeX Live there are `TEXMFLOCAL` for admin and `TEXMFHOME` for user pre-defined, but in MiKTeX there’s by default no local `texmf` tree installed, though it is useful, cf. [Purpose of local texmf trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/purpose-of-local-texmf-trees). Therefore my question:

*How do I create a local `texmf` tree in MiKTeX?*

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Actually you can create more than one local TeXMF folder! There’s already a description on MiKTeX’ online documentation, see [Integrating Local Additions](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html), at time of writing for recent MiKTeX 2.9 *(but the included images are from an older version, seemingly MiKTeX 2.5, and slightly different, cf. also http://docs.miktex.org/2.5/manual/localadditions.html )*. The denomination there is “User-Managed TEXMF Directory” *(see also additional note at the very end of this answer)*.

Anyway, here an alternative description:

- Create a folder somewhere on your computer – with an *important exception*. It **must not** be a subfolder of your MiKTeX installation (it worked this way in older MiKTeX versions, but was changed for security reasons). Avoid as far as possible spaces in the path, it is a potential risk for malfunction. For use with MiKTeX portable the folder must be, of course, on the same drive as the MiKTeX installation, it will be saved as relative path. Here I will use `c:\localtexmf`.

  This folder must be TDS compliant (see thereto [*A Directory Structure for TeX Files*](http://tug.org/tds/tds.html)); MiKTeX will complain, if not. What you need, depends on what you want to install into this directory, at least a `tex\latex` subtree should be sufficient. You will go safe, if you mimic the structure of the *(itself TDS compliant)* MiKTEX tree, but binaries can directly go into a subfolder `c:\localtexmf\bin`.
- Now, using the GUI:

  1. In the Start Menu go to the MiKTeX entry and open the settings – if you act as admin respectively “Settings (Admin)”, of course. The “MiKTeX Options” window will open.
  2. Go to the “Roots” tab. Click on “Add” and choose `c:\localtexmf\`. If there are more than one local directory, one can choose the search order with the “Up” and “Down” buttons.
  3. Now the almost most important part: Go to the “General” tab and click there on “Refresh FNDB” *(FNDB = File Name Data Base)*. In some cases, especially if new fonts are installed, one has to press also the “Update Formats” button.

  If you’d forget this step, all earlier steps would be done to no purpose.
- Otherwise, using the command line (as admin always add the switch `--admin`):

  Execute `initexmf --register-root=c:\localtexmf`, followed by `initexmf --update-fndb` (shorter: `initexmf -u`).

  (In every step you can add the switch `--verbose` to get more information about, what happens.)

  **Remark:** For compatibility reasons there’s also the older switch `--user-roots=<local-texmf-dir>`, what according to `initexmf --help` registers user root directories, I assume also in administrative mode, but in http://docs.miktex.org/manual/initexmf.html it is not mentioned any more, so I must guess.
- In the case, a `bin` subfolder for binaries was created, it should be registered in the environment variable `%PATH%` *before* the binaries subtree of MiKTeX own installation, see e.g. [How To Manage Environment Variables in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;310519) or a third-party tool like [Env-Man](http://env-man.blogspot.de/2007/04/envman-user-guide.html) or [RapidEE](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about). Then you need a system restart to take effect. An issue, that cannot be solved: A system wide environment variable, set by an admin, is always read before a user specific one. Then as a simple user you can only write and use batch files with an own `%PATH%` included.

All user created local texmf trees can be disabled by temporary removing from the MiKTeX roots (cf. additional note at the end).

*See also [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows).*

For the sake of completeness, here’s a description, how to remove a local TeXMF tree from MiKTeX, with `c:\localtexmf\` as example:

- GUI:
  Go again to the “Roots” tab in the settings (“MiKTeX Options” dialogue), select the directory `c:\localtexmf\`, and click on “Remove” on the lower side of the window. After that you must again refresh the FNDB and perhaps update the format files.
- Command line (also here: as admin add the switch `--admin`):
  Execute `initexmf --unregister-root=c:\localtexmf`, followed by `initexmf --update-fndb`. If you have uninstalled a font, additionally execute `initexmf --mkmaps`. The `--verbose` switch can be added, as well.
- If you do not need the `bin` subfolder anymore, the environment variable `%PATH%` must be cleaned up.
- Then the folder tree `c:\localtexmf\` could safely be deleted.

***Additional Note***

<sup>A hint first: In Command Prompt you can type `echo %Variable%` with `%Variable%` e.g. `%Userprofile%`. So you can see to which value the variables expand on your system.</sup>

Precisely the phrase *“in MiKTeX there’s by default no local texmf tree installed”*  in the question is not true. MiKTeX adds itself several trees under `%UserProfile%` and in admin mode also to `%AllUsersProfile%` (in the following the MiKTeX denomination comes first):

- “UserConfig”: `%AppData%\MiKTeX\<version>\`
- “UserData”: `%LocalAppData%\MiKTeX\<version>\` (since Windows Vista) or `%UserProfile%\<Local Settings>\<Application Data>\MiKTeX\<version>\` (until Windows XP, the strings `<Local Settings>` and `<Application Data>` are language dependent)
- *only in admin mode used* “CommonConfig” and “CommonData”: `%AllUsersProfile%\MiKTeX\<version>\` (since Windows Vista) or `%AllUsersProfile%\<Application Data>\MiKTeX\<version>\` (until Windows XP, the string `<Application Data>` is language dependent)

The actual paths you can see with the GUI in the “MiKTeX Options” window under the “Roots” tab or with the command line interface by executing `initexmf --report`.

Disadvantages of all these local trees: They can only be changed on installation, cf. [Changing the location of auto-installed packages in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82400/changing-the-location-of-auto-installed-packages-in-miktex), and they cannot be disabled (by temporary removing from the MiKTeX roots).

For additional information see [Difference between administrative and user mode of MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67712/difference-between-administrative-and-user-mode-of-miktex).

Comment: With my old MikTeX, I need to use `--user-roots` instead of `--register-root`. The good choice can be known by using `initexmf --help`.

Comment: in my case, i tried to register roots using the settings manager. This created hickups. `initexmf --update-fndb --verbose` showed, that my new roots were ignored for some reason. Therefore i encourage everyone to add roots via command line and check fndb updates using verbose...

Comment: I got an internal error, so I ended up just plasing the .sty file in the same directory as the .tex file.
MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\texmfroot.cpp
Line: 925

Comment: In my case, I had to create two additional folders in the "localtexmf" folder for this to work, that is the "bibtex" and "tex" folders.

Comment: What if miktex is installed to the root directory? (I was tired of typing long paths to compile my files.)  Then any directory `on the same drive` will automatically be a sub-directory of the miktex installation directory, and therefore ineligible.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Alex In fact I had the installation for years in `C:\MiKTeX`, and later in `C:\LaTeX\MiKTeX`, so `C:\localtexmf` is not a subdirectory. I do not see how to install something into `C:\ ` or: This would be not very wise.

Comment: @Speravir No, what had happened was, that I had a separate bootable USB dedicated to LaTeX, to which LaTeX was installed in the root directory.  This was when this problem started happening.

Comment: With MikTeX 4.0.1 console, the "Roots" tab is now "Directories"

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Yes, but don’t forget that my answer is more than 8 years old, now. Actually, quite a lot of myn answers are not fully up to date anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is the instruction in newer versions of MikTeX. Quoted parts are unchanged from [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/250119).

> - Create a folder somewhere on your computer – with an *important exception*. It **must not** be a subfolder of your MiKTeX installation (it worked this way in older MiKTeX versions, but was changed for security reasons). Avoid as far as possible spaces in the path, it is a potential risk for malfunction. For use with MiKTeX portable the folder must be, of course, on the same drive as the MiKTeX installation, it will be saved as relative path. Here I will use `c:\localtexmf`.

[Which is the best directory to keep my .sty files?](https://miktex.org/faq/local-additions)
contains some suggestion for where to place the folder.

> This folder must be TDS compliant (see thereto [*A Directory Structure for TeX Files*](http://tug.org/tds/tds.html)); MiKTeX will complain, if not. What you need, depends on what you want to install into this directory, at least a `tex\latex` subtree should be sufficient. You will go safe, if you mimic the structure of the *(itself TDS compliant)* MiKTEX tree, but binaries can directly go into a subfolder `c:\localtexmf\bin`.
>
> - Now, using the GUI:

1. Go to Start → MiKTeX → MiKTeX Console.
2. Click "Settings" (on the left pane) → "Directories" tab → "+" button →
   select the path.
3. "Tasks" (menu entry) → "Refresh file name database".

> - Otherwise, using the command line (as admin always add the switch `--admin`):
>
>   Execute `initexmf --register-root=c:\localtexmf`, followed by `initexmf --update-fndb` (shorter: `initexmf -u`).

Note that `initexmf --register-root=<path>`, the `<path>` must be an absolute path. So it must start with `c:\` or something.

> (In every step you can add the switch `--verbose` to get more information about, what happens.)